# How to customize map controls using Gmaps4rails gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

i've got confused trying to change the map controls like said [here](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html) But don`t know how to implement using gmaps4rails gem.

I just wanted to leave only zoom and pan control and remove all the others. But js console says for:

```
 >> Gmaps.map.map.mapTypeControl
 >> false
```

But it is still present on a map.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a `raw` parameter to send any map option you need. [See doc](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Map-Apis).

I guess, you should do:

```
<%= gmaps(:map_options => { :raw => '{ panControl: true,
                                       zoomControl: true,
                                       mapTypeControl: false,
                                       scaleControl: false,
                                       streetViewControl: false,
                                       overviewMapControl: false}' 
                          },
          :markers => { :data => @json  } 
)%>
```

Comment: With the above raw options, i am able to hide every thing except terms of use. can you help me in hiding this terms of use   link while rendering the maps? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are initialising with javascript (not with `<%= gmaps %>`), use

```
Gmaps.search_map.map_options.raw.streetViewControl = false;
```

More options [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions)